# RxJava 2 assembly process

Tags: rx-java2, reactivex

I have a question about assembly process of RxJava2. What is the main purpose of this process? When is attribute onObservableAssembly (RxJavaPlugins) set to null or to reference? And is possible to watch implementation of functional interface with apply method which is used in onAssembly method? You can explain case with Observable.just(1,2,3) and with filter. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The assembly process is when operator chains are established to form a template for the dataflow realized later via a `subscribe()` call. Assembly hooks are advanced concepts, typically not needed by most users, to inject custom operators when the static/final methods of `Observable` are called.

Use cases could be:

- Adding debug operators that capture the current stacktrace when the assembly happened, possibly giving extra information where to look in case of crashes.
- Replacing specific operators with other custom operators.
- Shimming custom operators that validate the flow for protocol adherence.

The default assembly hooks are `null` which means the originally intended operators will carry on.

Example usages can be found in the [extensions project](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#debug-support). With `just` and `filter`, you could do such things:

```
RxJavaPlugins.setOnObservableAssembly(o -> {
    if (o instanceof ObservableFromArray) {
        return new ObservableFromArray<>(new Integer[] { 4, 5, 6 });
    }
    return o;
});

Observable.just(1, 2, 3)
.filter(v -> v > 3)
.test()
.assertResult(4, 5, 6);

RxJavaPlugins.setOnObservableAssembly(null);
```